# Retrofit gives SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit in my Android App. When I make request with 'https://example.com' as the base url it works fine. But when I make request with 'https://www.example.com' as a base url It gives SSLHandshakeException. I am not understanding why it is happening.

Comment: have you read retrofit docs? it might be mentioned there

Comment: yeah I have gone through documentation. I have not seen describing about it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have used it with 2.2.0

Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains

```
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                   }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager

        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.interceptors().add(httpLoggingInterceptor);
        client.readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.connectTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
       keyStore.load(null, null);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
       trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "keystore_pass".toCharArray());
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        client.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
                .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
               });

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Common.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client.build())
                .build();

        serviceApi = retrofit.create(Api.class);
```

thanks hope this will help you. Sometime ssl version 1.2 or lower not installed in server side as well.

Comment: The same thing is happening with the Glide library. Is it a problem of the certificate? Should I have to make any change on the server ?

Comment: What change needs to be done on the server in order to solve it. We have changed the ssl certificate on the server some days ago?

Answer (score 0):

> OkHttp has removed support for obsolete HTTPS configurations and the
>   host you’re trying to reach needs to be updated.

If you don't want to do that you can configure cipher suites and TLS versions in `OkHttp` to support this obsolete server.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomCipherSuites.java

From my understanding this will ensure that all the overlapped CipherSuites are used. Here are the results I got from testing it on different Android versions:

**OkHttp 2.3.0**

> 5.1 - working
>   5.0 - working
>   4.4.4 - error
>   4.3 - error
>   4.2.2 - error
>   4.1.1 - error
>   4.0 - error

**OkHttp 2.2.0**

> 5.1 - working
>   5.0 - working
>   4.4.4 - working
>   4.3 - working
>   4.2.2 - working
>   4.1.1 - working
>   4.0 - error

Comment: We have installed a ssl certificate on the server. Is this problem can be solved by some modification done on the server?

Comment: I think it won't be the reason. Just try any other URL without `https`.